# Performance of Firebase with large data sets

Tags: firebase

I'm testing firebase for a project that may have a reasonably large numbers of keys, potentially millions.

I've tested loading a few 10k of records using node, and the load performance appears good. However the "FORGE" Web UI becomes unusably slow and renders every single record if I expand my root node.

Is Firebase not designed for this volume of data, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: As Kato mentions below, this is a Forge issue, not a Firebase issue. Try navigating directly to a deeper path to handle larger datasets.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It's simply the limitations of the Forge UI. It's still fairly rudimentary.

The real-time functions in Firebase are not only suited for, but designed for large data sets. The fact that records stream in real-time is perfect for this.

Performance is, as with any large data app, only as good as your implementation. So here are a few gotchas to keep in mind with large data sets.

**DENORMALIZE, DENORMALIZE, DENORMALIZE**

If a data set will be iterated, and its records can be counted in thousands, store it in its own path.

This is bad for iterating large data sets:

```
/users/uid
/users/uid/profile
/users/uid/chat_messages
/users/uid/groups
/users/uid/audit_record
```

This is good for iterating large data sets:

```
/user_profiles/uid
/user_chat_messages/uid
/user_groups/uid
/user_audit_records/uid
```

**Avoid 'value' on large data sets**

Use the `child_added` since `value` must load the entire record set to the client.

**Watch for hidden `value` operations on children**

When you call `child_added`, you are essentially calling `value` on every child record. So if those children contain large lists, they are going to have to load all that data to return. Thus, the DENORMALIZE section above.

Comment: Do you mean, if we just want to get everything about an user just like display a user profile page then we use `"This is bad for iterating large data sets"` methods, otherwise, if want to display a list of user  example for admin use then we use `"this is good for iterating large data sets method"` ?

Comment: @vzhen pretty much, the trick is remembering that when you call child_added or value (it doesn't matter which) that you are downloading all data under that path, including all children, and not just the root level element you asked for.

Comment: As Kato mentioned, child_added is named a little bit confusingly since it also returns all data under a path regardless of when it was actually added.  If you want "event whenever a new child is added", you'll need to do something like `ref.limitToLast(1).on('child_added', ...`.

Comment: how `child_added` on `/users/uid/chat_messages` is different from `child_added` on `/user_chat_messages/uid`? I want to use the first approach but will never have any listener directly on `/users/uid`.

Comment: @ZeeshanAli Not sure if you found out already. But this will be slow when using the `/users/uid/chat_messages` setup and you want to fetch the user info to show on a profile page. It'll fetch ALL `chat_messages` along with it. Use different data paths, and connect based on an id. In short: the `This is bad for iterating large data sets`-approach will easily slow down your app, where the `This is good for iterating large data sets`-approach will make it very hard to slow down your app.

Comment: Is it realistic to expect to make 1000 database queries per request? About how long will that take?