# How to structure firebase data for user inputted search terms that are substrings / partials of record?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'll preface this by including existing (and useful) firebase data structure references:

https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html

[What's the best way of structuring data on firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421179/whats-the-best-way-of-structuring-data-on-firebase/16423051#16423051)

[Firebase data structure and url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638660/firebase-data-structure-and-url)

However, what I'm looking for is something more synonymous with MySQL's WHERE LIKE, i.e. the ability to return records that *include* a given substring.

Specifically, I want to provide users with a way to search all (public) users of an app (by username / name / email / phone / all of these).

I don't want to download all users and then use angular filters / alternative client side filtering, as this could become a large download as the user base scales (especially if the search is across multiple collections - e.g. username, name, email etc.)

I've considered using a tree structure, for example:

```
- users
   - username
      - a
         - an
            - and
              - andy
              - andr
                - andre
                  - andrea
                  - andrew
         - ann
            - anne
```

Then I could reference users/username/a when a user types in 'a', users/username/a/an for 'an' etc. and effectively only reference a subset of the users based on the search term.

Considering the NoSQL nature, along with the advice to denormalise data and keep the structure flat, **does this structure make sense?**

Or, **is there an alternative / better way to do a LIKE esque query?**

Comment: Update: according to this firebase post https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-01-02-queries-part-two.html
it seems the best current solution is by using elasticSearch 
http://www.elasticsearch.org/
on your server

Comment: Firebase supports filtering data by *name* by *priority*. As soon as you need more than that, you'll need to create an "index" node somewhere else in your Firebase, where you store references to the data under a different *name* or *priority*. In the blog post you refer to, Elastic Search is used to automatically create and maintain such indices.

Comment: See also [this search algorithm post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034860/firebase-how-to-match-opponents-in-a-game/25039133#25039133)

Comment: Thanks - ended up following firebase.com/blog/2014-01-02-queries-part-two.html which works well.