# Firebase push and set multiple nodes atomically with security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, angularfire2

I've read [Firebase data consistency across multiple nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947898/firebase-data-consistency-across-multiple-nodes), the multi update stuff works as expected, however I don't know how to do the following:

Let's say I have 2 collections: `answers` and `posts`. Now I want to write an answer to a post and increment the answers counter on the post object keeping the data consistent between collections. So the actual objects look similar to these:

**post**

```
{
   ...,
   answers: X
}
```

**answer**

```
{
   postID: <random string>,
   ...
}
```

As I said above, that link answers how to do a merged update, however, how can I be sure that the `answers` property will only be incremented/decremented (in case of deletion) by 1? What I have so far is this:

```
"answers": {
  ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && (newData.val() === data.val() + 1 || newData.val() === data.val() - 1)"
}
```

Obviously that would work (I assume, haven't tried), but that would still allow me to **create** a new answer and **decrement** the counter. How can I overcome that issue?

Comment: To keep a count in sync with the underlying collection, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954217/is-the-way-the-firebase-database-quickstart-handles-counts-secure/37956590#37956590

Comment: Thanks, will take a look!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen One question though: your suggested method requires me to know the answer's key before the update, but I don't, since I want to push **and** update the counter the same time. Is this supported? I'm kinda getting confused. :/

Comment: Nvm, I can create a new key client side! I guess I just gotta read your answers on SO, lol. Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "key". My code reads the voteCount before writing it. It essentially replaces Firebase's transaction mechanism with a custom one, so that it can use a multi-location update.

Comment: I meant that I can do something like `updates['answers/' + ref.push().key]` and then effectively push a new answer even if it's an "update".