# Best Practice Data Relationships and Selecting with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried to understand how to structure data in Firebase, but I'm struggling to apply the examples to what I have, some advice would be great.
[Image of Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5ekv.jpg)

I have a list of portfolios. Each portfolio has a name and its own key (probably bad practice, but I couldn't work out how to get the key easily in my JS).

I have a list of orders. Each order has a name and portfolio attribute set to the key of the portfolio it belongs to.

1. Do I have to store order ID's in my portfolio?
2. How do I get a list of orders where order.portfolio equals portfolio.key?

I've tried to use equalTo, however I don't think I'm using it correctly.

```
    firebase.database().ref("orders").orderByChild("portfolio").equalTo(thisref.portfolio.key).on('value',  function(snapshot) {
      var orders = snapshot.val();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

See answer to related question here: [What's the best way of structuring data on firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421179/whats-the-best-way-of-structuring-data-on-firebase)

I'm practical terms personally I download all the data into a local "store" and then "join" the data as I need it based on the I'd On the record. So

1. Yes
2. Download both sets on app initiation and then use a for loop or a lodash filter to get all orders for given portfolio