# How scalable is Firebase dashboard?

Tags: firebase

n case of rather large dataset with million+ objects, how scalable is firebase dashboard (web interface)? 
On test project all changes in dataset are immediately propagated to browser. However in case of large project the browser will not be able to handle it, or will be?

if I have the index structure:

```
update_index:{
  object_00000001:{},
  object_00000002:{},
  .
  .
  object_99999999:{}
}
```

and there are constant changes on various elements. Is there a way only to indicate a change in dataset without passing data to snapshot and propagate the changes on user request?
How is it handled in firebase dashboard?

Answer (score 3):

Its difficult to understand what you're asking. Assuming you mean Forge for the dashboard, then Forge will load all the data in your firebase, which can be an expensive operation, and can definitely be slow. Additionally, if you're opening an object with any more than a couple hundred keys then it becomes quite slow.

Every read operation in firebase is done with a .on or a .once as far as I'm aware, and you can listen for 'child_changed' event type but the only way to handle read data is with a snapshot.

If you're referring to Forge in your question, this may help: [Performance of Firebase with large data sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239819/performance-of-firebase-forge-with-large-data-sets)

Comment: yeah, my bad, I indeed meant Forge. thanks