# How to implement the pagination in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, pagination

How to implement the pagination in react native? not using srollable view, list view or load more function. The pagination function got the next, previous button and current page selection in react native, may I know it can be done in react native? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pagination in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49452707/pagination-in-react-native)

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find a solution for this either so I created a plugin for this https://github.com/garrettmac/react-native-pagination

but to answer your question the magic is done in the `onViewableItemsChanged` prop function that pops out two params one the returns an array of changes items and the other that that returns an array of visable items you can use those to track and manipulate your array to position correctly depending how you're doing your pagination. I'm answering this from mobile but I think ListView, Flatlist (which you should use over ListView) and SectionView all share this prop. Good luck

Comment: Hi, I have tried your example but only the Horizontal Paged Example it works but the others returned with the error message "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'element.props')", may I know can you solve the issues? Thank you also for posting the answer.

Comment: @Vyga hi, should we limit our lists when fetching long lists of data to be displayed in react native. Are there performance issues if we do that? I am using firebase as backend.

Comment: @Yasir Then i think this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/16240601/4642530

Comment: Hi @garrettmac, can we use this pagination npm for Flatgrid?